# How I can make a button for browse a folder?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I try to search a folder and when I find to copy the address in a `textBox1` .I have the next code, but this doesn't work properly, with this code I just find the files. My question is : How can I change the code to make a browse button for find a folder and when I find to copy the address in `textBox1`?

```
private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    fDialog.Title = "Browse";
    fDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\LegacyApp\MATLAB\R2008a_64-bit";
    fDialog.Filter = "All files(*.*)|*.*|All files(*.*)|*.*";
    fDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
    fDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = fDialog.FileName;               
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing with this code

Comment: this code was created to find a file, when the button open are press an message appear " File not found."

Comment: and if it possible I want to have in browse page three buttons "ok", "Cancel " and "make new folder"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To browse folder, you need [FolderBrowserDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
     {
         textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following

```
textbox1.Text = fdialog.FileName.Substring(0, fdialog.FileName.lastIndexOf(@"\"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried like follows, Its working for me.

`private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fDialog = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                Title = "Browse",
                InitialDirectory = @"C:\LegacyApp\MATLAB\R2008a_64-bit",
                Filter = "All files(*.*)|*.*|All files(*.*)|*.*",
                FilterIndex = 2,
                RestoreDirectory = true
            };
            if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = fDialog.FileName;
            }
        }`